# discord.js v12 info command always showing offline status

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make a command that show info about a specific user, the command works fine but the status of the user always shows as **offline**

This is the main part of the info code that shows the status of the user

```
if (user.presence.status === 'online') status = `${client.config.emojis.ONLINE}Online`  ;
if (user.presence.status === 'idle') status = `${client.config.emojis.IDLE}Idle`;
if (user.presence.status === 'dnd') status = `${client.config.emojis.DND}Dnd`;
if (user.presence.status === 'offline') status = `${client.config.emojis.OFFLINE}Offline`;
if (user.presence.clientStatus != null && user.presence.clientStatus.desktop === 'online') plateforme = '️ desktop'
if (user.presence.clientStatus != null && user.presence.clientStatus.mobile === 'online') plateforme = ' Mobile'

let permissions_arr = userInfo.permissions.toArray().join(', ');
let permissions = permissions_arr.toString()
permissions = permissions.replace(/\_/g, ' ');

const embedMember = new MessageEmbed()
    embedMember.setFooter(`ID: ${userInfo.user.id}`,``,true)
    embedMember.setThumbnail(userInfo.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    embedMember.setColor(`${client.config.color.EMBEDCOLOR}`)
    embedMember.setTitle(`${userInfo.user.tag}`)
    embedMember.addField('Joined:', `${moment.utc(userInfo.joinedAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY \n -HH:mm')}`, true)
    embedMember.addField('Account created:', `${moment.utc(userInfo.user.createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY \n -HH:mm')}`, true)//
    embedMember.addField('Status:', `${status}`, true)
    embedMember.addField('Roles:', `${userInfo.roles.cache.map(r => r.toString()).join(' ')}`)          
message.channel.send(embedMember);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User status is part of the user's presence. In order to access the presence of guild members, you must subscribe to the `GUILD_PRESENCES` [intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents). This is what the construction of your `Client` object will need to look like:

```
const bot_intents = ["GUILD_PRESENCES"];
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: bot_intents, ws:{intents: bot_intents}});
```

Because presences are a privileged intent, you will also need to go to your bot's application page in the Discord Developer Portal and enable this setting:

[image]

You can, of course, add any other intents you may need/want to the `bot_intents` variable. This answer assumes you are not already using the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent, as you did not mention it in your question.

Comment: This answer is meant for discord.js v12, and is the answer to the original question as this was asked at the time intents were introduced. For those of you who are downvoting this answer because of newer issues in discord.js v13, go look at questions/answers designed for djs v13 instead.